Why the Standard Part and not the Significant Part?
In nonstandard analysis the justification for dropping the differentials with lower orders of smallness is in terms of the standard part, which rounds off all infinitesimal parts of a finite hyperreal and returns ∞ for any unlimited hyperreal.  It is commonly said that doing this, defining the derivative as $$st(\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x})$$ allows one to restore almost exactly the infinitesimal reasoning of the pre-Weierstrass greats.
But if the goal is to use infinitesimals in their full glory, as the likes of Euler and Leibniz did, why the standard part and not the significant part?  Instead of rounding off everything that isn't a "real", why not round off everything lower than the highest order of infinity present in an expression?  That would follow the reasoning of the Analysts of old more closely, as they tended to think and argue in terms of differentials rather than in terms of derivatives
So then you'd have for instance: $$dy=sp((x+dx)^2-x^2)$$ In the case of a parabola. Where "sp" stands for "significant part".  This way you could argue with differentials directly, and the place of the independent variable is the one where the increment is a constant infinitesimal $h$ rather than a variable, since the independent variable is equivalent to setting a given differential to a constant.
So my question is why the standard part and the derivative as the centerpiece of non-standard analysis, instead of the significant part and the differential?  Is there some kind of gnarly pathological counter-example that the differential quotient can't handle but the derivative can?

You want the infinitesimal parts to vanish which means restricting the expression to the standard part. That's how it was done originally, as elucidated by Fermat's adequality.

"why not round off everything lower than the highest order of infinity present in an expression?" Because this is meaningless; there are no "orders of infinity" in nonstandard analysis, certainly not "in" a given hyperreal.

In your approach with the "significant part", what would be the differential $dy$ at the point $x=0$ when $y=x^2$?

@MikhailKatz Evaluation of $dy$ would occur after the significant part operation had been applied, so $dy|_0= 0$ for $y=x^2$.  $d$ is an operator that acts on functions, rather than on points, after all.

Yes but if one performs the calculation of the differential quotient one gets $\frac{(x+dx)^2-x^2}{dx}=\ldots=2x+dx$, which at $x=0$ should produce the lowest-order term $dx$ rather than $0$.  So according to your "significant part" approach, apparently $dy$ should be $dx$, not $0$.

But it isn't $\frac{(x+dx)^2-x}{dx}$, its $\frac{sp((x+dx)^2-x)}{sp((x+dx)-x)}$.  Since $dy$ is equal to the significant part of the difference, not the difference itself.

According to your prescription for the "significant part", for $y=x^2$ we are to take $sp((x+dx)^2-x^2)=sp(2xdx+dx^2)$.  When $x=0$, this gives $sp(0+dx^2)=dx^2$ (what else could it be?).  Then the differential quotient at $x=0$ would give $\frac{dx^2}{dx}=dx$, which is not the traditional value that one expects at $x=0$.
Thus the approach with such a "significant part" is incoherent.  That's why the standard part is used in NSA.
More details can be found at Is there an algebraic-geometric solution to the problem of the Leibnizian formalism?

+1. Let we have for moving particle $y=t^2$. If $dy=0dt$ for t=0 then will particle rest along tangent line $dt$ time? @Mikhail Katz

I think I understand.  But the idea was that $sp(f(x+dx)-f(x))|_a$ is allowed, but $sp(f(x+dx)|_a-f(x)|_a)$ isn't allowed.  That the $d$ operator has to finish operating before evaluation can happen.  Is this kind of restriction I'm talking about something that is coherent?  Or does it break something else?  Am I even making sense?

If one is looking for generalisations of the standard part, there is a little bit one can do in the following direction.  By the transfer principle, every hyperreal $x$ has an integer part $n$, so that $0\leq x-n<1$.  Furthermore, one can take the standard part $r = st(x-n)$ to obtain a real number $0\leq r \leq 1$.  Then an arbitrary hyperreal $x$ decomposes as the sum $x=n+r+\varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon$ is infinitesimal.   The hyperinteger $n$ can of course be infinite.
